# Paypal Rest API Multiple Payee

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, multiple-accounts

Can i have more than one payee using REST API in Paypal?

https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal/php?interactive=ON&env=sandbox

The above link does not make it clear and was the most useful.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have more than one payee for one transaction. However you can have more than one receiver. Here is some information on Adaptive Payments.

[PayPal Adaptive Payments Integration Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/)

Here is the general information on Adaptive Payments directly from PayPal Documentation:

**Adaptive Payments** provides several methods of payment: simple, parallel, and chained payments. Each method of payment is called with the Pay API; the payment method is determined by how the request is structured.

**Simple payments** allow a sender to send a single payment to a single receiver. This is the traditional way that payments are made. Your website could use an Adaptive Payments checkout flow for transferring money from a sale from your customer’s PayPal account to your own account.
 
**Parallel payments** allow a sender to send a single payment that is split directly among 2 to 6 receivers. Your application might be a shopping cart allows a buyer to pay for items from several merchants with one payment. Your shopping cart distributes the payment to merchants that actually provided the items. PayPal then deducts money from the sender’s account and deposits it in the receivers’ accounts. 
**Chained payments** allow a sender to send a single payment to a primary receiver. The primary receiver keeps part of the payment and pays secondary receivers the remainder. For example, your application could be an online travel agency that handles bookings for airfare, hotel reservations, and car rentals. The sender sees only you as the primary receiver. You allocate the payment for your commission and the actual cost of services provided by other receivers. PayPal then deducts money from the sender’s account and deposits it in both your account and the secondary receivers’ accounts.